# Taking the logarithm of the integrand

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, logarithms

Say you have a function, $f(x)$. Is there any way to write the expression,

$$ \int \ln(f(x)) \, \mathrm{d} x$$

in terms of

$$ \int f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$$

Or just some other way to simplify or deal with the logarithm inside the integral?

Comment: Not Really, @Nikhil . You have to implement $f(a+b-x) $ type tactics. Could you post the question in which this part is coming in?

Comment: It comes from a problem where the integrand is a product of two functions and I need to separate the product into two additive terms - which I can do easily by taking the logarithm. But I don't know how this will change the final integral!

Comment: Btw, the '$f(a + b - x)$' tactics you mentioned are fine. Just as long as I can get an indicator of how the integral is affected as a whole!

Comment: what you mean by "in terms of $f$"? The integral $\int\ln(f)$ is already written in term of $f$. If you use the power expansion of the logarithm you will get a more complex expression of powers of $f^k/k$.

Comment: I didn't say "in terms of $f$". I said, in terms of $\int f$.